# Batch Merge csv

Tags: csv, batch-file, text

I written a script that merges all csv files within a location to txt. The merge works fine apart from it seems to add a -> after the last row of data. Is there anyway of stopping this additional line from being included or removing it

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

 if exist "C:\DND\tempfile.txt" (del /Q "C:\DND\tempfile.txt")
 copy "\\jarvisFS1\Groups\InforIFC\Payroll\New\*.csv" "C:\DND\tempfile.txt"
 for /f "delims=" %%f in (C:\DND\tempfile.txt) do (
 set var=%%f"
 set var=!var:"=!
 set var=!var:,= !
 echo !var! >> "C:\DND\EPRO.txt"
  )
 del /Q "C:\DND\Tempfile.txt"
 Move "C:\DND\EPRO.txt" "\\jupiterinfor\Import Master\IM_Files"
 Move "\\jarvisfs1\groups\InforIFC\Payroll\NEW\*.csv" 
 "\\jarvisfs1\groups\InforIFC\Payroll\PROCESSED"
```

I have attached a screen shot

Screen Shot

Comment: Please include the screen-shot by `edit`ing your post and using the `picture` button (looks like the sun over some mountains)

Comment: The copy command will put an End of File marker when copy in ASCII mode by default.  If you don't want the EOF then use the /B switch at the end of your copy command.

Comment: @Squashman, Thank you where do i need to put the /b switch within the command?

Comment: The last 7 words of my previous comment: **at the end of your copy command**

Comment: @Squashman. thanks added the /B which worked.  my next question is how would I go about removing the space at the end of each row. As the file seems to add a space. Example: 750.15(Space)

Comment: Don't ECHO the extra space when you are writing to the output file.